# jQuery .each() always returns Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I'm trying to list search results by using the jQuery `.each()` method. Unfortunately it seems to always output `undefined`, even though I defined it in my array.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
     "count":2,
     "results":[
             {
                 "title":"AirMech\u00ae Arena",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
             {
                 "title":"Game Title 2",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
             {
                 "title":"Game Title 3",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
      ]
}
```

And then I try to do the each like this:

```
$.each(results, function(index, value) {
    $("#search-results").append(value["results"]["name"]);
});
```

I've tried `value["results"][0]["name"]`, `value[0]["results"]["name"]`, `value[0]["results"][0]["name"]`

And it always seems to return the undefined error, no matter what I try.

What can be the cause?

---

**Updated code**

```
            $.each(results, function(index, value) {
                $("#search-results").append(value["title"]);
                alert(value["title"]); // alerts undefined
            });
```

Comment: results is not array

Comment: Are you in need of title instead of name? results does not have any key named name

Comment: You don't have a property named `name`!

Comment: Not only that, his code was looking for `results.results.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `name` key in your object. Instead, you're probably looking for `title`. Also, you are looping on `results` so `value` in your each function *is* `results`. There is no `results.results` so it was returning `undefined`.

Updated to assign your object to a var called `myObject`.

```
var myObject = {
     "count":2,
     "results":[
             {
                 "title":"AirMech\u00ae Arena",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
             {
                 "title":"Game Title 2",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
             {
                 "title":"Game Title 3",
                 "releasedate":"2015-05-05T00:00:00Z",
                 "icon":""
             },
      ]
}
```

This should work for you:

```
$.each(myObject.results, function(index, value) {
    $("#search-results").append(value.title); // <-- you have title not name
});
```

If you wanted to grab the keys using the syntax you used, this would also work:

```
$.each(myObject.results, function(index, value) {
    $("#search-results").append(value["title"]); // <-- you have title not name
});
```

Check out the working demo: https://codepen.io/mccambridge/pen/pKYbWv

Comment: It seems this code loops twice as intended but returns undefined, I've updated my question with the code I used

Comment: It might be the way you're calling this. Your object wasn't assigned to a `var` so check out my edit and the working codepen demo.

Comment: That indeed was the problem, the mystery has been solved! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

As I can see your Json object, If you read it carefully, you are trying to access the key **results** and then under **results** you have only three subkeys which are

- title
- releasedate
- icon

I can't find Name key in this, but while accessing, you are writing :

```
value["results"]["name"]
```

How will you be able to access the key **name** if that doesn't exist in the object?

If you are looking for title :

```
results[0].title
results[0].releasedate
results[0]. icon

results[1].title
results[1].releasedate
results[1]. icon
```

I think this will help you and help you clear your logic too. So in your loop it will be :

```
$.each(results, function(index, value) {
    $("#search-results").append(value.title);
    $("#search-results").append(value.releasedate);
    $("#search-results").append(value.icon);
});
```

Comment: @J.Doe I haven't added the loop in my answer, I have updated it now. Imagining you are trying to loop through the names. Can you check it now? I checked and it prints the tiles.

Comment: The values seem to return `undefined`. When adjusting it a bit to `value.results.title` it outputs a console error, but when using your example it only outputs undefined

Comment: @J.Doe Here is a working JSfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/342591/ If you do console you will be able to see the titles.

Comment: @J.Doe My answer and logic are correct but you were storing it under a different name, so I just wanted you to understand the concept, sorry for not providing a copy-paste solution. But yes, mccambridge got it right.